# Typescript - Express allowed array combination at the type level

Tags: typescript

Given the following:

```js
type EventType = "TYPE A" | "TYPE B";
```

I would like to type an array so that it can only have either `TYPE A` OR `TYPE B` or both.

I could type it as an `EventType[]` but that allows duplicates

```js
type Test = EventType[]

const eventTypes:Test = ["TYPE A", "TYPE B", "TYPE B", "TYPE A"]
```

I could explicitly list out the available options, but this quickly explodes when you have more than two options

```js
type Test = ["TYPE A"] | ["TYPE B"] | ["TYPE A", "TYPE B"];

// compiler error
const eventTypes:Test = ["TYPE A", "TYPE B", "TYPE B", "TYPE A"]
```

Is there anyway to express this at the type level in typescript without explicitly enumerating all options?

Comment: What would the explicit list look like for 3 options?

Comment: No there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work

```
const eventTypes = ["TYPE A", "TYPE B"] as const
type Test = [typeof eventTypes[number]] | typeof eventTypes

const onlyA: Test = ["TYPE A"]
const onlyB: Test = ["TYPE B"]
const all: Test = ["TYPE A", "TYPE B"]

// compiler errors
const duplicate: Test = ["TYPE A", "TYPE A"]
const emptyArray: Test = []
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgNzmKAVAngBzhGBeGAbQCJUBNABQFEYBBYgGhlMpoCFiBdGAQ11EhQAUFCxwYqHLAKFR2EADN4SFBmwRCYAK4BbAEZwATp24AfGHLiLlyNGIhChA6DHAAbdLQBcEqfiIs1HRcTuAu7uhsPpIuMoHsIc6wPG5u0X5x5EH0TPEwHJyOAPRFMKA6mACWbkbwhoYghg5JMAAmWphulcA8UHDpsQFZNDnMw8GFLXAVorT1POgD0kScQA)

Comment: This fails with more than 2 options (ie `["TYPE A", "TYPE B", "TYPE C"`])